# Custom dialog unwanted bottom space

Tags: android, android-dialog

I'm creating a custom Dialog (not a DialogFragment or AlertDialog!).

My point is that it should be with fullscreen tint and buttons aligned bottom with some small margin (I'm cloning iOS ActionSheet dialog. Sorry for that - not my idea :( ).

I've created a dialog that's falls behind NavBar (I guess this is needed for background tint to be fullscreen), then I add some padding to dialog window - the same as NavBar height.

It works ok, but it has some additional bottom padding or margin - I can't find out where it comes from.

This is Dialog's theme:

```
<style name="ActionSheetDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ActionSheetDialogAnimationTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

This is how I patch dialog window's size and bottom padding:

```
private void patchDialogSize() {
    WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    int width = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = manager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    params.copyFrom(getWindow().getAttributes());
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);

    Resources resources = getContext().getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        int bottomPadding = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        Log.info(TAG, "NavBar height = " + bottomPadding + ", will be set as bottom padding");
        dialogContainer.setPadding(0, 0, 0, bottomPadding);
    }
}
```

Log writes me that `I/ActionSheet﹕ NavBar height = 96, will be set as bottom padding`

It looks like this:

[image: unwanded_space]

If I remove all bottom paddings and margins in dialog layout and remove that NavBar height patching, it looks like this:

[image: still]

According to my logic, on last screenshot button should be lower behind NavBar, so it's some unwanted padding about 10 or 15 dp.

Can someone help me figure out where that comes from?

**P. S.:** just realized: NavBar says it is 96dp height. It's approx same height as my button, which is 50dp. So NavBar height is calculated incorrect, but why?

**P. P. S.:** again - sorry for aping iOS look and feel - truly not my idea.

Comment: Why are you setting `android:windowFullscreen="true"`? Just set the window gravity to be `BOTTOM` and add whatever padding you need.

Comment: Tried that - didn't do any difference.